# Matlab Find number of consecutive zeros

Tags: matlab, matrix, series

I want to find the lengths of series zeros in a matrix

```
A = [0 0 0 3 1 4 6 0 9 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 5 2 1 1;2 3 1 0 0 4 6 0 0 0 2 3 8 6 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
```

I need result gives seriesZeros = [3 1 6;2 3 5] and also [rows,cols] from series of zeros value
thank you very much...

Comment: Have a you tried anything? The least you could do is formatting your question a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this as follows:

```
A = [0 0 0 3 1 4 6 0 9 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 5 2 1 1;
    2 3 1 0 0 4 6 0 0 0 2 3 8 6 0 0 0 0 0 1 1];


[N,~] = size(A);

% pad A==0 with zeros, and calculate diff for each row
A2 = diff([zeros(N,1) A==0 zeros(N,1)],[],2);

out_mtx = [];

for row_i = 1:size(A2,1)
    row = A2(row_i, :);
    zero_lengths = find(row == -1) - find(row == 1);
    out_mtx(end+1,:) = zero_lengths;
end

out_mtx
```

Which gives

```
out_mtx =

     3     1     6
     2     3     5
```